# Watin - Element caching

Tags: c#, javascript, html, watin, web-testing

I am using C# and Watin.

Imagine the following scenario:

I search for an element using it's innerHTML/Find.ByText.

```
return Document.Element(Find.ByText(Localisation.CommandHeader));

CommandHeader.SetAttributeValue("Innerhtml", "Save Template");
CommandHeader.SetAttributeValue("onclick", "..");
```

I then change the elements text, and want to add a onclick event on it using Element.setAttributeValue. 
Now Watin throws an Exception, telling me it can't find the element with criteria Innerhtml(..).

Saving the Element to a local variable did not help.

What I also tried, is adding CommandHeader.Refresh() between the two commands.

By the time of writing I came up with the idea of first assigning an id to the element, and then access it by only using that as selector afterwards. However, I didn't test it yet.

Is there a better way? Any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You can only SET attribute value but you can't create a attribute through WatiN. If `InnerHtml` attribute is already existing then you can.

Comment: @Sham The attribute already exists. But why can't one do that? Doesn't make much sense to me, to require javascript to create new attributes. Watin should really have that feature..

Comment: WatiN do not have API which does that.WatiN is mainly for Web UI testing and as part of testing no one does creation/updation of attributes.